How does the avx2 version compress operation in Kyber (ML-KEM) work?
I'm currently focusing on the implementation of Kyber (ML-KEM).
I noticed that the avx2 version of the compress operation seems to use a fast division algorithm.
ref version here: https://github.com/pq-crystals/kyber/blob/main/ref/polyvec.c#L51
avx2 version here: https://github.com/pq-crystals/kyber/blob/main/avx2/polyvec.c#L11
I am confused about how the avx2 aversion works, and what is the algorithm behind that.
Besides that, there is another implementation of the compress10 method:
// input "a" is a polyvec
//Here q is 7681, not same as current Kyber (ML-KEM)
const __m256i fdiv = _mm256_set1_epi16(8737);//fast division // floor(2^26 / q + 0.5)
const __m256i hfq = _mm256_set1_epi16(15);
for(int i = 0; i < K; i++) {
  for(int j = 0; j < 256; j++) {
    d0.vec = _mm256_loadu_si256((__m256i *)&a->vec[i].coeffs[16 * j]);

    d0.vec = _mm256_slli_epi16(d0.vec, 2);
    d0.vec = _mm256_add_epi16(d0.vec, hfq);
    d0.vec = _mm256_mulhi_epi16(d0.vec, fdiv);
    d0.vec = _mm256_srli_epi16(d0.vec, 2);

    ......
  }
}

I summarized the formula above is: (((x*4 + 15) * 8737) >> 16) >> 2.
Its ref version is like:
....
uint16_t t[4];
for (i = 0; i< K; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j< 256/ 4; j++)
    {
        for (k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
            // PARAM_Q here is 7681
            t[k] = ((((uint32_t)a->vec[i].coeffs[4 * j + k] << 10) + PARAM_Q / 2) / PARAM_Q) & 0x3ff;
        }
// other loop operations
....

But I found out that when the poly coefficient is 5772, the ref version will get the compressed result as 769, while the avx2 version generates 770. I ran 20 groups of test vectors for avx2 version and ref version (code I mentioned above, Kyber's both versions are correct all the time), this is the only case that shows different results between the two versions. It seems like a precision issue.
I don't know why and also don't know how the optimized algorithm (both the Kyber version and another version I mentioned above) works (or does not work).

Kyber compression with $d=10$ maps a variable $x$ to
$$\left\lfloor\frac{2^{10}}q\cdot x+\frac12\right\rfloor\mod 2^{10},$$
note that if $0\le x<q$ then the mod operation is unnecessary as the result after the floor function lies in the range. Presumably the avx2 code assumes that this input sanitisation has been performed.
The avx2 would to eliminate the division by $q$ operation. If we consider the expression
$$\frac{2^{28}}q\cdot x+2^{17}$$
(which is less than $2^{32}$, then this is simply the content of our floor function multiplied by $2^{10}$, and if $0\le x<q$ our floor operation returns the 10 highest bits of our new expression.  This expression still has a division by $q$ however.
Next we observe that
$$\frac{2^{28}}q\cdot x+2^{17}=\left(2^2\cdot x+\frac q{2^9}\right)\left(\frac {2^{26}}q\right).$$
Because $q=7681=15\cdot2^9+1$, we can usually get away with approximating our first bracket with the integer $4x+15$. Similarly $2^{26}/q\approx 8736.996$ is very well approximated by 8737. This gives
$$\frac{2^{28}}q\cdot x+2^{17}\approx (4x+15)\cdot 8737$$
and so the top ten bits of this quantity are usually the same as the compression function.
To be little more precise, the left bracket is less than $2^{15}$, the right bracket is less than $2^{12}$; changing $q/2^9$ to 15 is a change of $2^{-9}$; changing $2^{26}/q$ to 8737 is a change of less than $2^{-7.8}$. It follows that the change in the product of our brackets is approximately  less than $2^{15}2^{-7.8}+2^{12}2^{-9}\approx 2^{7.2}$. Therefore if our rounded expression is further than, say, $2^8$ from a power of $2^{18}$, the top 10 bits of our 28-bit expression are unaffected.
However, in the case $x=5772$, we see that $(4x+15)\cdot 8737=1100000010000000000000011111_2$ is very only 31 greater than multiple of $2^{18}$, so it is possible for the rounding to give a different result (as indeed is the case).
Returning inconsistent compression values is a security vulnerability (the well-formedness check in Kyber decapsulation depends on it) and the avx2 code for the $q=7681$ case should not be used.

That's impressive!
But I don't know why when $x=5772$ (i.e., when result of $(4x+15) \cdot 8737$ is close to a multiple of $2^{18}$), the approximations do not work?

@Tall: I've expanded a bit; let me know if you'd like further clarification.

I'm still a little confused. To simplify the expression, let's assume $2^2 \cdot x + \frac{q}{2^9}$ is denoted as A, and $\frac{2^{26}}{q}$ is denoted as B. Then $(A \cdot B) >> 18$ is exactly the same as previous floor function. So far A and B still means a real number, and now we need to approximate A and B to further see if the result divided by $2^18$ could still approximate $(A \cdot B) >> 18$. Then we do the above approximations as you pointed out, this gives $(A - 2^{-9})\cdot(B+2^{-7.8})$, which is $AB-2^{-9}B+2^{-7.8}A-2{-16.8}$.

So the change of the result $\approx -2^{-9}B+2^{-7.8}A \approx 2^{7.2}$. So only if the approximation $A \cdot B + 2^{7.2}$ would not affect the upper 10 bits, the result divided by 2^{18} could stay the same as $(A\cdotB) >> 18$. So if I don't get it wrong, this may be the reason for Therefore if our rounded expression is further than, say, $2^8$ from a power (multiple?) of $2^18$, the top 10 bits of our 28-bit expression are unaffected. But I'm still confused, it seems like no carry bit to the top 10 bits is enough to keep 10 bits unaffected, and why close to $2^{18}$ is a judge condition

Going past a multiple of $2^{18}$ is the condition for a carry bit to propagate into the top 10 bits.

Thanks, I fully understand it now. By the way, is there any mitigations for the case $q=7681$ to use AVX version code? Is it possible to lower the change loss, or this approximation ($(4x + 15) \cdot 8737$) is the best one?

To further extend the answer, I found a mitigation method to fix the inconsistency between the avx2 version and ref version.
The key point is what we discussed above: find if the $(4x+15)\cdot8737$ is close to the multiple of $2^{18}$ enough.
The above result, say $2^8$, is a rough approximation, if we want to ensure the result is correct, we need to find the relatively tight bound.
Luckily, the case $q=7681$ is small enough to enumerate all possible inputs to find a bound. So I finally found that, if the least 18-bit of $(4x+15)\cdot8737$ is less or equal then $2^6$, we need to adjust the final result by subtracting it by 1.
Here is the PoC in Python:
q = 7681
def compress_ref(x):
    return ((x << 10) + (q // 2)) // q

def compress_avx(x):
v = 8737
f0 = (x << 2) + 15
f0 = (f0 * v)
f0_hi = f0 >> 16
f0_lo = f0 & 0xffff
res = f0_hi >> 2  
if f0_lo <= 2**6 and f0_hi & 0x0003 == 0:
    res -= 1
return res

not_eq = []
for i in range(0, q):
    ref = compress_ref(i)
    avx = compress_avx(i)
    if ref != avx:
        not_eq.append((i, ref, avx))

print(len(not_eq))
print(not_eq)

